# Rewrite $\arctan(\cos(x))$ such that the new expression has no reference to trigonometric functions (9th-grade Trigonometry Test Question)

Tags: trigonometry

> Rewrite $\arctan(\cos(x))$ such that the new expression has no reference to trigonometric functions.

This was an extra-credit question on my 9th-grade trigonometry test. I tried creating a right triangle where one of the angles is $\cos(x)$ with a hypotenuse of $1$ and a leg of $x$. Could I get some redirection?

Comment: Have you found the length of the other leg?

Comment: By the Pythagorean theorem it is sqrt(1- x^2). If I set an angle to cos(x), then the tan(cos(x)) = x/ sqrt(1- x^2) or  sqrt(1- x^2)/x

Comment: Since $x$ is an angle, it would be better to set $\cos x = t$ so that you do not confuse angles and side lengths.  Also, are you studying unit circle trigonometry or just right triangle trigonometry?

Comment: We have been studying both, but more unit circle in the past few days. The test had both unit circle and right triangle trigonometry.

Comment: Perhaps, the problem was supposed to be some thing like $\cos(\arctan(x))$ (with the inverse function inside). Your approach would work then. It won't work with what you have (in your setup, $\cos(\cos (x))=x$).

Comment: I thought that too but the teacher confirmed he wanted it like this

Comment: We know $\cos(\pi/3)$ is $1/2$.  It this works, we would get a simplification of $\arctan(1/2)$.  I believe that is not yet known.

Comment: You can do it with logarithms and complex exponential, but otherwise it is impossible. Look at [OEIS sequence A101923](https://oeis.org/A101923) for some formulas.